# How to extract the csv output displayed by solr query output using R or PowerShell?

Tags: r, powershell, solr

I am trying to save data as a 'csv' format file or extract as a data frame from a solr query similar to this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=ipod&fl=id,cat,name,popularity,price,score&wt=csv
```

I get a response as a web page output as shown below:
[image]

I am able to copy, paste, save and retrieve the data in csv format from the csv output displayed in html file (webpage solr output) manually. However, I couldn't automate the process using R. I am neither able to parse and get the entire content by `unlist` -ing the output in the correct order nor extract and save the content displayed in the web page as a csv file. I tried `solrium` and `httr` packages in vain. I also tried to `Export-Csv` option in Windows PowerShell to save the data in a csv file format without any luck.

Requesting suggestions to overcome the issue.

Comment: For PowerShell, you would not use `Export-CSV` that is for turning  Objects into a CSV. You have a flat text file in CSV format already, so it would better to use `Out-File` or `Set-Content`

Comment: @BenH, with your suggestion, I am able to save the output as csv file. However, I am not able to read the file as a csv file. Every row is one long line and I am not able to read the file using R for parsing. Is there a remedy for this?

Comment: `solrium` maintainer here: I'm not sure i understand the problem. Does `solrium` give you a data.frame as you'd expect? if so, can't you write that to disk as a csv with `write.csv` or other equivalents?

Comment: @sckott, I saw many of your posts/replies/suggestions in this forum and first tried your package. The problem was I could not extract the data as data frame from the csv  format solr query result displayed in the web page. If you can suggest on how to achieve this it would help me immensely.

Comment: @RanonKahn answer below - does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't address anything specific about powershell, but as a start using `solrium`, does this work, and if not, how does it fail:

(to be fully reproducible), setup Solr

```
cd solr-6.6.0
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
bin/solr create -c techproducts -d sample_techproducts_configs
bin/post -c techproducts example/exampledocs/*.xml
```

In R:

```
solr_connect()
(df <- solr_search(
        name = "techproducts", 
        q = "ipod", 
        fl = c("id", "cat", "name", "popularity", "price", "score"), 
        wt = "csv"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>                id                   cat                                       name popularity  price     score
#> *           <chr>                 <chr>                                      <chr>      <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1           IW-02 electronics,connector             iPod & iPod Mini USB 2.0 Cable          1  11.50 3.2388113
#> 2 F8V7067-APL-KIT electronics,connector  Belkin Mobile Power Cord for iPod w/ Dock          1  19.95 2.3162508
#> 3       MA147LL/A     electronics,music Apple 60 GB iPod with Video Playback Black         10 399.00 0.9044058

write.csv(df, "myfile.csv", row.names = FALSE)

readLines("myfile.csv")
#> [1] "\"id\",\"cat\",\"name\",\"popularity\",\"price\",\"score\""                                                   
#> [2] "\"IW-02\",\"electronics,connector\",\"iPod & iPod Mini USB 2.0 Cable\",1,11.5,3.2388113"                      
#> [3] "\"F8V7067-APL-KIT\",\"electronics,connector\",\"Belkin Mobile Power Cord for iPod w/ Dock\",1,19.95,2.3162508"
#> [4] "\"MA147LL/A\",\"electronics,music\",\"Apple 60 GB iPod with Video Playback Black\",10,399,0.9044058"
```

Comment: How do I authenticate access?

Comment: in `solr_connect` you can set your proxy details if using that. otherwise, you can pass options to the HTTP request via `callopts`, e.g, `callopts = httr::authenticate(user = "foo", password = "bar")` to do simple auth

Comment: so `url` param in `solr_connect` is just the base url for the solr instance. not the additional url parts, those are handled in each of the functions, e.g., `solr_search` adds `/select` for you. I'm working on improving the connection class with more fine grain control - watch https://github.com/ropensci/solrium/issues/100

Comment: Thanks a lot @sckott. I will be eagerly watching.

Comment: e.g., `solr_search(callopts = httr::authenticate("foo", "bar"))` - similarly, can do `httr::use_proxy()` for proxy

Comment: I am not able to replace cli <- SolrClient$new() in place of solr_connect(). Can you please help?

Comment: I am since  last 6 months running a Rshiny app that uses solrium package with solr_connect function without an issue. But after updating the solrium package I am not able to use solr_connect function and I am not able to replace it with solr_client$new() function. Please help!

Comment: I did. But bit confused. I have emailed you the code I am using. I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Per BenH's comment, its already in CSV format so no need to use `Export-CSV`. Just use the `-OutFile` parameter on `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=ipod&fl=id,cat,name,popularity,price,score&wt=csv" -OutFile YourFile.csv
```

Comment: I am getting a XML output instead of a csv output. Is there a way to convert/parse xml output from the query and save it as a csv file?

Comment: Try `Invoke-RestMethod` instead. You might be getting other stuff from Invoke-WebRequest which explained the XML looking data.

Comment: With Invoke-RestMethod I am able to save the output as csv file. However, I am not able to read the file as a csv file. Every row is one long line, and I am not able to read the file using R for parsing. I am getting "appears to contain embedded nulls" error.  Is there a remedy for this? However,  I am able to open the file in Excel using Data Input option after parsing the file as a comma delimited file.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of novices like me I am sharing the solution.

**The PowerShell approach:**

**Step 1**:  I used the following PowerShell code saved as .ps1 file.

```
curl 'https://some_site.com/solr/some_folder/select?q=*:*&wt=csv' -L -u username:password --location-trusted -b cookie-jar.txt > OutputFilename.csv
```

**Step 2**: I used the following R script to run the PowerShell file and read the csv file generated by PowerShell as a data frame for further processing.

```
system2("PowerShell", args=c("-file", "C:\\FolderName\\FileName.ps1"))
df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("OutputFilename.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-16LE"))
```

**Using the `solrium` package by Scott Chamberlain approach:**

```
library(solrium)
solr_connect("https://site.organization.com", errors = "complete") 
solr_search(name = "studies", q = "metadata:value", rows=1000, wt = "csv", callopts = httr::authenticate("usrname", "pwd"))
```